# Limit logarithm $\lim_{n \to \infty}(4n-6)[\ln(2n+5)-\ln(2n-7)]$.

Tags: limits, logarithms, infinity

please any advice for this limit?
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}(4n-6)[\ln(2n+5)-\ln(2n-7)]$$
Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\ln(2n+5)-\ln(2n-7)=\ln(\frac{2n+5}{2n-7})=\ln(\frac{2n-7+12}{2n-7})=\ln(1+\frac{12}{2n-7})\sim\frac{12}{2n-7}$

So your limit is equivalent to $\frac{12(4n-6)}{2n-7}\sim24$

Comment: Thanks a lot, please how you get this  ln(1+12/(2n−7))∼12/(2n−7) ?

Comment: @David it should be in your lesson if you studied equivalence. $\ln(1+x)\sim_{x->0}x$